# Read variables from a file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, readfile

I have a variable called `words` in Javascript like this:

```
var words = [{"text":"This", "url":"http://google.com/"},
         {"text":"is", "url":"http://bing.com/"},
         {"text":"some", "url":"http://somewhere.com/"},
         {"text":"random", "url":"http://random.org/"},
         {"text":"text", "url":"http://text.com/"},
         {"text":"InCoMobi", "url":"http://incomobi.com/"},
         {"text":"Yahoo", "url":"http://yahoo.com/"},
         {"text":"Minutify", "url":"http://minutify.com/"}]
```

and I use the variable elements as for example `words[0].url` which points to the first url, i.e `http://google.com/`, etc.

If I store the data in a file like this (I call it file.csv):

```
This, http://google.com/
is, http://bing.com/
some, http://somewhere.com/
random, http://random.org/
text, http://text.com/
InCoMobi, http://incomobi.com/
Yahoo, http://yahoo.com/
Minutify, http://minutify.com/
```

How can I read the file in Javascrip and re-create variable `words`, with the exact same format as I mentioned earlier, i.e re-create:

```
var words = [{"text":"This", "url":"http://google.com/"},
         {"text":"is", "url":"http://bing.com/"},
         {"text":"some", "url":"http://somewhere.com/"},
         {"text":"random", "url":"http://random.org/"},
         {"text":"text", "url":"http://text.com/"},
         {"text":"InCoMobi", "url":"http://incomobi.com/"},
         {"text":"Yahoo", "url":"http://yahoo.com/"},
         {"text":"Minutify", "url":"http://minutify.com/"}]
```

Comment: Why not store the contents in JSON instead of CSV?

Comment: Sure, I can do that to. But then how to read and create `words`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are two steps.  First is to get the external file, and the next step is to get it into a format you want it.

If you're not using jquery, first step is:

```
var file = new XMLHttpRequest();

file.onload = function() {
  alert(file.responseText);

}

file.open('GET', 'file.csv');
file.send();
```

Next step is to take that file.responseText and format it.  I might do:

```
var file = new XMLHttpRequest();
var words = [];


file.onload = function() {

   var lines = file.responseText.split("\n");

    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        var word = {};
        var attributes = lines[i].split(",");
        word.text = attributes[0];
        word.url = attributes[1];
        words.push(word);
    }

}

file.open('GET', 'file.csv');
file.send();
```

If you're using a JSON file, just change the function above to be:

```
file.onload = function() {
    words = JSON.parse(file.responseText);
}
```

Keep in mind that the words variable will not be available until the onload function runs, so you should probably send it to another function that uses it.

Comment: Thanks, based on previous suggestion I created a JSON file. Now is is easier to read the file? Can you help me to read JSON file and store the results in words?

Comment: Sure, if you like the answer, make sure you 'accept' it :)  Answer is updated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `fetch API`, it has many advantages and one of them is very short syntax, unlike the `XMLHttpRequest` constructor.

```js
fetch("object.json").then(function(data){window.data=data.json()});
//then access the data via [window.data]
```